# Definite places of rebirth (request of sources from Buddhas sutras)

Tags: sutras, rebirth, sutta-reference

I'm looking for sources from the 4 nikayas on where, and how to "attain" a defined place of rebirth.

Examples I know of:

- Heinous actions lead to definite hell realm rebirth
- Reaching sotapanna stage is defined human or above rebirth (in a noble family)
- Anagami, defined rebirth in pure realm (non returner)
- Higher levels of jhana, defined pure realm rebirth (this may be incorrect?)
- Attainment of 4 immeasurables, defined bhrama realm rebirth (brama-vihara)

If there are any other sources anyone knows where the Buddha defined specific actions that lead to specific places of rebirth, this would be very helpful.

I know Mahayana, specifically Tibetan sects have concocted some practice known as Tulka, where apparently a high level Bodhisattva can choose where to be reborn, but I find these claims dubious at best and the practices trying to define and find the person reborn as flawed divination!
I would prefer actual Buddhas teachings on sources rather than unsubstantial claims.

Answer (score 0):

An example from  the suttas is porn or "prostitutes" lead to lower realms ([Snp 1.6](https://suttafriends.org/sutta/snp1-6/)). Hell is described by King Yama in [MN 130](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.130.than.html). Otherwise, this leads to animal birth ([AN 2.9](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an02/an02.009.than.html)).

All ten unwholesome actions can lead to hell ([AN 10.211](https://suttacentral.net/an10.211/en/bodhi?lang=en&reference=none&highlight=false)). The five heinous actions seem to refer merely to five actions an Ariyan cannot commit ([MN 115](https://suttacentral.net/mn115/en/sujato?lang=en&layout=linebyline&reference=none&notes=sidenotes&highlight=false&script=latin)). The five heinous actions do not define what leads to hell. All ten unwholesome actions can lead to hell ([AN 10.211](https://suttacentral.net/an10.211/en/bodhi?lang=en&reference=none&highlight=false)).

> **There is the case where a trifling evil deed done by a certain
> individual takes him to hell**. There is the case where the very same
> sort of trifling deed done by another individual is experienced in the
> here & now, and for the most part barely appears for a moment.
>
> Now, **a trifling evil deed done by what sort of individual takes him to
> hell**? There is the case where a certain individual is undeveloped in
> [contemplating] the body, undeveloped in virtue, undeveloped in mind,
> undeveloped in discernment: restricted, small-hearted, dwelling with
> suffering. **A trifling evil deed done by this sort of individual takes
> him to hell**.
>
> Now, a trifling evil deed done by what sort of individual is
> experienced in the here & now, and for the most part barely appears
> for a moment? There is the case where a certain individual is
> developed in [contemplating] the body, developed in virtue, developed
> in mind, developed in discernment: unrestricted, large-hearted,
> dwelling with the immeasurable. A trifling evil deed done by this sort
> of individual is experienced in the here & now, and for the most part
> barely appears for a moment.
>
> [AN 3.99](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an03/an03.099.than.html)

[image]  [image]